# SimpleImputer object has no attribute _fit_dtype

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dev-to-production, scikit-learn-pipeline

I have a trained `scikit-learn` model pipeline (including a `SimpleImputer`) that I'm trying to put into production. However, I get the following error when running it in the production environment.

```bash
SimpleImputer object has no attribute _fit_dtype
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of using different versions of scikit-learn in the development and production environments. The model has been trained using one version and then it's used with a different version.

This can be solved by storing the current library versions in the development environment in a `requirements.txt` file using:

```
pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

In the production environment, install the same library versions with:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```